# Numpy/Scipy Connected Components

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, connected-components, ndimage

I am writing a program in python to find "islands" of 1s, 0s or -1s in a L*L matrix.
I need It to find these "regions" of connected components, label each one of them, and be capable of returning, for a given element of the matrix m[x][y] , the size of the island it belongs to.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
from scipy import misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = np.random.randint(-1,2,(L,L))

mask1 = (m == -1)
mask2 = (m == 0)
mask3 = (m == 1)

label_m1, nb_labels1 = ndimage.label(mask1)
label_m2, nb_labels2 = ndimage.label(mask2)
label_m3, nb_labels3 = ndimage.label(mask3)
```

This should give me labelled islands for a random matrix m (just an example), but I do not know how to get the size of the "region" a given point belongs to.
Could you help me? I have almost no programming experience, so forgive me if the question is silly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
label_count_m1 = np.bincount(label_m1.ravel())
label_count_m1[0] = 0
sizes_m1 = label_count_m1[label_m1]
```